# Is there anywhere that photographers can exchange twitter follows or other social media connections directly?

Tags: service-recommendation, social-media

Just looking for like minded people and there are lots of people out there!

Essentially somewhere to get a look at some profiles and follow what you like etc.

A network if you will.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Photo.SE. I find it hard to understand what you're asking, hence it is hard to give you an answer to the question. Please take a moment to read the [Asking section in the help centre](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to understand how to ask questions on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I a not really sure what you are asking for either...but: 500px.com, 1x.com, flickr.com...just to name a few...all have ways of linking with and publishing to twitter, facebook, pinterest, etc.

Comment: @dpollitt http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4054/is-photo-se-exclusively-for-expert-level-questions

Comment: I've restored the original title, as I am not sure the edited one and the original actually ask the same thing. I understand the reason for the edit...but given the controversy, I think it best to leave the content be for the time being.

Comment: It wasn't my intent to change the meaning with the title edit, which was largely based on the last line of text in the question itself -- "A network if you will".

Comment: I'm struggling to read the question in an other way, in fact. So, I guess that means that voting to close as unclear is the best approach. Rob, can you clarify?

Answer (score 4):

In general, I think they are called [Flickr.com](http://www.flickr.com/), [500px.com](http://500px.com/), [deviantART.com](http://www.deviantart.com/), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Either jump in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography) here or go to a photo sharing site such as one of the ones that jrista mentioned.  There are very, very many options out there.  Photo sharing sites like flickr and 500px probably are the easiest kind of thing if you are looking to find photographers whose style you like.

Answer (score 2):

Flickr is a pretty good place to start.  You can browse peoples photostreams and find people to follow via. the Explore homepage to start, then start adding your favourite photographers as contacts.  You then see them on your own home screen next time you log in.

Answer (score 1):

Google+ seems to be the most active social network for photographers to hang out with each other. It treats the photos pretty well visually, but the communities are also quite good for building discussion around topics rather than just dropping images on each other. The community I founded, Bird Photography (https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/110212420118174844279) has just passed 2500 members and I think it has a nice mix of sharing imagery with each other and discussion, critique, gear talk, etc.

To me, it's not really a social network unless folks are actually talking and sharing knowledge. Right now, the best place to find that for photographers is G+.

Comment: You need some numbers to back up the statement that Google+ is most active since in terms of users it has a very low usage compared to other social networks, especially given google's anti-competitive efforts.

Answer (score -1):

To specifically address the Twitter part of the question, it's unlikely there are such services and if there are don't expect them to stick around as it's against the Twitter API terms to export content to other services that includes follows.